# Trying to pass a String to bound function C++

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-esp8266

In this example, how do you pass a String to the bound "handler" function?

```
// MyClass.h

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(ESP8266WebServer& server) : m_server(server);
    void begin();
    void handler(String path);    
protected:
    ESP8266WebServer& m_server;
};

// MyClass.cpp
...
void MyClass::begin() {

  String edit = "/edit.htm";

  m_server.on("/edit", HTTP_GET, std::bind(&MyClass::handleFileRead(edit), this));
...
```

Every which way I try I get:

```
error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
```

Comment: You are trying to *call* `MyClass::handler` as a static member function.

Comment: What is the full type of `String`?

Comment: Try `m_server.on(uri, HTTP_GET, std::bind(&MyClass::handler, this, String(uri));`  Or, maybe a lambda will work instead:  `String str_uri(uri); m_server.on(uri, HTTP_GET, [this, str_uri]() { this->handler(str_uri); });`

Comment: this worked.  thanks @RemyLebeau `server.on("/edit", HTTP_GET, std::bind(&SolarServer::handleFileRead, this, path))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
std::bind(&MyClass::handleFileRead(edit), this)
```

you attempt to ***call*** `MyClass::handleFileRead(edit)`, and take the pointer of the result as the argument to the `std::bind` call. This is of course not valid, especially since the function doesn't return anything as well as it's not being a `static` member function..

You should not *call* the function, just pass a pointer to it (and set the argument):

```
std::bind(&MyClass::handleFileRead, this, edit)
//                                ^       ^
// Note not calling the function here     |
//                                        |
//       Note passing edit as argument here
```

Answer (score 0):

lvalue required as unary '&' operand is saying that a variable is required to take the address from. In the case of your method:

```
void begin(const char* uri) 
{
    m_server.on(uri, HTTP_GET, std::bind(&MyClass::handler(&path), this));
}
```

path is undefined - so in this case path is not an addressable variable. As mentioned in the comment above, by @Remy Lebeau, if you pass in the param uri - then you have a valid addressable variable.